# git p4 clone/sync: how to add new P4 path

Tags: git, perforce

I created a P4 client view spec and made a git-p4 clone with it, and periodically sync changes from P4, it works very well. 
One day I want to add another P4 path to the Git repository I cloned, it stucks. Even I added the new path to my client view spec used by git-p4 clone, it does not bring the new path to Git repository. Is it possible to do so?

Best Regards,

Comment: Did you pass `--use-client-spec` to `git p4 clone`?

Comment: I've described (what I believe to be) a working solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376692/extending-git-p4-clientspec-after-initial-clone (even though this question was asked first, I think that the other question was slightly better worded).

Comment: A different solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175539/git-clone-multiple-p4-paths-in-one-git-repo.  I comment in both of these answers explaining why jamesdlin's worked for me, but the other one did not.

Comment: Agreed the other is worded well.  My web search found the other, did not find this one.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I can use "git-p4 sync" to add new path besides adding the new path to client spec. So the solution should be:

1. Add new path to cient view spec and ensure p4 can sync the path;
2. Run "git-p4 sync  " to add the new path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will add the new path to the Perforce tree, but it doesn't automatically add it to the Git tree. (Using `git p4 rebase`/`git p4 sync` will add files from that path to your git tree *if* the imported Perforce changes happened to touch those files, but untouched files won't be imported.)