# git clone multiple p4 paths in one git repo

Tags: git, perforce

I know that if I need to clone a perforce an existing p4 repository using command

```
git p4 clone //depot/path/project
```

But what if I want to multiple p4 paths into one git repo?
say I have the following structure

```
    //depot---/Path1----/APath/...
           |          |
           |          |
           |          --/BPath/...
           |       
           |     
           ---/Path2----/CPath/...
           |
           |
           ---/Path3
```

I only want to clone files under ***//depot/Path1/APath/*** and ***//depot/Path2/CPath/*** in my local directory ***~/Desktop/mylocalRepo/***
how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at Perforce's git integration (Git Fusion)?

Answer (score 5):

The solution that I found was clonning different Perforce paths into different Git repositories and later merge them into a new repository while keeping the history.

```
//depot/Projects/A
...
//depot/Projects/C
//depot/Projects/...
```

Clonning Perforce repository into git:

```
git p4 clone //depot/Projects/A@all
git p4 clone //depot/Projects/C@all
```

Then create an empty Git repository:

```
mkdir project
cd project
git init
```

Add repositories path:

```
git remote add -f a ../A
git remote add -f c ../C
```

Merge Project A:

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories a/master
```

Move Project A into a subdir:

```
mkdir dir_a
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name ".git" -and -not -name "dir_a" -exec git mv {} dir_a/ \;
```

Commit changes:

```
git commit -m "Merge Project A"
```

Merge Project C:

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories c/master
mkdir dir_c
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name ".git" -and -not -name "dir_a" -and -not -name "dir_c" -exec git mv {} dir_c/ \;
git commit -m "Merge Project C"
```

Using Git:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1
```

Comment: This method makes sense to me. But it failed for me because I had crlf issues, probably due to my use of cygwin with a binary mount point. When I tried to use git config core.autocrlf true to workaround the crlf differences, that resulted in a different issue. In the end I followed a different set of instructions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376692/extending-git-p4-clientspec-after-initial-clone , and that avoided the crlf issue. Note that I did use --use-client-spec when I did git p4 clone, then later I added more paths to my p4 client's workspace view.

Comment: I did have success with this. One issue I did find was the history gets duplicated when there is a p4 commit across multiple folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `--use-client-spec` option to git-p4. See the "CLIENT SPEC" section in the [git-p4 documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-p4.html).

When you use this option, git-p4 uses your Perforce client view to map depot paths into your Git repository. By setting up a Perforce client with the mappings you want, you can selectively import parts of your Perforce depot.

Comment: This is just a repeat of the documentation. An example would be more helpful.

Comment: Also, the P4 documentation states: "Note: The (untested) git p4 clone --use-client-spec command line option restricts Git-p4 to files that are visible within a Perforce client view. Unfortunately, --use-client-spec is untested, and using it can result in missing files, or exclusion/minus-mapped lines incorrectly treated as inclusions."

Comment: While this answer looks like it might be correct, it isn't. The `--use-client-spec` flag has no effect on what is cloned where.